# Seeking suggestions for working around a crawl space vent when building a deck

Tags: deck, vent, crawlspace

Our home is a 1950s split level in IL. Our split level deck's step is shorter than code, everyone trips on it, and the homeowner is legally blind. We need to level the deck for safety.

Raising the lower deck covers one of the two crawlspace vents. Village code requires vents for crawlspaces without a cement floor and mechanical ventilation. Our space has a dirt floor covered by a vapor barrier and is encapsulated. Any ideas on how we can work around this?

[image: Short step]
[image: Current state of affairs]
[image: Vent blocked]

Comment: You can build a box in front of the duct and pot sturdy screen on top to maintain air flows in/out.

Comment: Is that your only vent? Converted encapsulated crawlspaces have many vents from when they were vented. Is it possible to open up one of the others and close off this one?

Comment: There are three vents. One is blocked by the deck floor on other side of the door.

Comment: With the deck boards running along that wall, I'd think you'd be able to drill out a number of holes in the rim-joist along that 12-18" section to allow air flow _through_ the rim joist. Stagger the holes (1/2" should be sufficient, I'd think) horizontally and you won't significantly weaken the joist. You could even add a bolt on either side to attach the rim joist to the house.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear exactly which piece of new construction wood is blocking the vent.  Assuming it's one of the joists touching the house wall, it seems to me you should be able to cut a gap in that joist to clear the vent, and then "head off" that gap with additional cross-joists, rather as you would head off a window opening in a wall.